# kdb: Efficient way to delete last row from a table?

Tags: kdb

For example, creating this 20M row table takes 37ms, but deleting a row takes 38ms! Is there any way to do this more efficiently?
(In place modify is fine as I don't need the original)

```
q)n:20000000
q)t:([]a:n#1;b:n#2)
q)\t t:([]a:n#1;b:n#2)
37
q)\t t:-1_t
38

/ in place delete doesn't seem to help either
q)\t delete from `t where i=last i
67
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Various approaches you would hope to work are limited by the fact that a copy of `t` is being created (inspect the `peak` value of `.Q.w[]` before and after either your delete query or using Drop if you need convinced of this). Your lowerbound on execution is going to be limited by the time it takes to construct `t`.

Comment: As a consequence, consider either including a flag column to indicate whether the row is active, or combining that with an ‘immutable’ approach in which the original tuple is ‘deleted’ by appending a copy with the flag down.